# On Thompson conjecture

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $N(G)$ be the set of conjugacy class sizes of finite group $G$. Let $G$ be a finite group for which $N(G)=N(A_n)$, where $A_n$ is the alternating group of degree $n$.

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct prime numbers satisfying $n/2<p,q<n$. Moreover, assume that the Sylow $p$-subgroups and Sylow $q$-subgroups of $G$ are cyclic. Is it true to say if $x\in G$ is of order $p$, then $q\mid|x^G|$?

Comment: Why do you say every non-identity conjugacy class of $A_n$ has size divisible by $p$ or by $q$?

Comment: I was mistaken.

Comment: Professor Holt, I cannot follow it would you please explain more?

Comment: @DerekHolt : That is true within $A_{n}$, but is it clear that that property carries over to $G$?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I think I have misunderstood the question. So $G$ is any finite group in which the set of conjugacy class sizes is equal to the set of conjugacy class sizes in $A_n$. I will retract my vote to close.

Comment: @DerekHolt : Yes, I think that is what is intended. As you can see, I was caught out too.

Comment: What is Thompson's conjecture? Also do we just know the set of conjugacy class sizes, or do we know it as a multiset? In the latter case we would know the order of $G$.